# Cause viewDidLoad to run

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating a new `UIViewController` but waiting a few seconds before I'm showing it.
The thing is I want `viewDidLoad` to be called before I'm actually showing the now object. How can I make `viewDidLoad` run?

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
UIView *tempView = newObject.view;
```

But I really don't like that solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like just calling `[newObject view];` does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

If there is code that you want to run that you want to be called when the view is instantiated then just put it in the `init` method.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName: nibNameOrNil 
                           bundle: nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Custom stuff
    }
    return self;
}
```

Is there another reason why you are wanting `viewDidLoad` to be called?

Comment: Some of the code I'm running there relates to the view object

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (void) viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.view.alpha = 0; //When alpha = 0, it is also hidden
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
            // Nothing to animate here
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // On animation completion show the content of the view, also animated.
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                self.view.alpha = 1;
            }];
        }];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The viewDidLoad is always called before the object is shown in screen.
If you want some delay , you can set some delay code inside viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear. But why exactly do you need the delay , there may be other solutions to solve your issue.